# Show that an integral is less than 1/2

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am having trouble with the following problem:

Show that

$$ \int_0^\infty   \frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi} (1+\arctan(x))}dx \le \frac{1}{2}  $$

I would appreciate any guidance in the matter, we are working on a unit of sequences and series.

EDIT: Adding more detail of what I have tried

I found a function that is always greater than or equal to the integrand over the range of interest, namely

$$    \frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}    $$

The integral of the second function is equal to 1/2. Therefore, the integral of the original function must be less than 1/2, proving what was requested. However, the maker of the problem seems to be requesting a solution using series, which is giving me trouble. I was thinking of using a Taylor series of the second function, but I am not sure that would help.

Jim

Comment: So many downvotes and close votes seem unfair while similar questions do not receive such a harsh treatment. I agree that the poster should give some more detail, though.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I guess the *harsh treatment* is a conquence of the triviality of the question: it is enough to exploit $\arctan(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: i have only a numerical Expression for that